# Does the decimal expansion of a (fractional) number always contain less digits than its binary expansion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, binary, decimal-expansion

I have been doing some conversions of fractional binary numbers to decimals, and I noticed a pattern: the decimal expansion always had $\le$ digits than the binary expansion. For example:
$$\begin{align*}
(0.1)_2 & = (0.5)_{10}\\
(0.01)_2 & = (0.25)_{10}\\
(0.001)_2 & = (0.125)_{10}\\
(0.1001101)_2 &= (0.6015625)_{10}
\end{align*}$$
Does this pattern hold in general? I thought about this problem, and I was able to come up with a proof of the following *weaker* claim.

**Claim:** If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ has a finite binary representation, then it has a finite decimal representation.

**Proof (Sketch):** $x$ is a finite sum of numbers of the form $2^{-j}$. The set $$S = \{y \in \mathbb{R}| y \text{ has a finite decimal representation} \}$$
is closed under addition, so it suffices to prove that numbers of the form $2^{-j}$ have finite decimal representation. But $2^{-j}$ is just $1$ divided by $2$  repeatedly, and $S$ is closed under division by $2$, so $2^{-j}$ is in $S$ for every $j$.

Comment: Hint: a number with $n$ bits after the point is of the form $x = a / 2^n$ for some integer $a$, but then $10^n x = \dots$

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for the hint! I am thinking...

Comment: @dxiv Yeah so $x = \frac{ 5^n a}{10^n} = \frac {m}{10^n}$. Now $0<x<1$ implies that $m < 10^n$ so $m$ is an integer with $<  n$ digits. Therefore $\frac {m}{10^n}$ should have exactly $n$ digits as well.

Comment: Actually, that implies $x$ has *at most* $n$ decimal digits. But assuming $x=a/2^n$ is a fraction in lowest terms, $a$ must be odd, so $m=5^na$ is also odd, and therefore $m$ cannot be a multiple of $10$ i.e. $m/10^n$ will have exactly $n$ decimal digits.

Comment: @dxiv Oh right, something like $500/1000 = 0.5$ has only one decimal digit. And $\frac{a}{2^n}$ will always be in lowest terms, because when we add the fractions $\frac{1}{2^{k_1}} + \frac {1}{2^{k_2}} + \cdots + \frac {1}{2^n}$ the numerator will be the sum of an even number with $1$, which is odd. Therefore if $0<x<1$ has a binary expansion of $n$ digits, then $x$ has a decimal expansion of $n$ digits. But the converse is not true, as $(0.1)_{10}$ does not have a finite binary expansion.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you so much for helping me with this!